# Updating buttons in dynamic web user control in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hope to explain my problem clearly.

I have a asp.net page (default.aspx) with a ScriptManager, an UpdatePanel containing a PlaceHolder (PlaceHolderUC) and two buttons (btnAddControl and btnRefreshPage) triggered to this UpdatePanel.

I have a Web User Control (UControl.ascx) with a table containing some html controls:

- a textbox (txtOrder) where I store the order number of the control itself; it is useful for me to understand if the sorting works; then it will be replaced by a hidden control
- a label (lblTest) where I write the name of the control (eg. Control #1)
- a textbox (txtTest) where, when i run the project, I write some text to test persistence of the controls
- a button (btnMoveDown) to move the control downwards
- a button (btnMoveUp) to move the control upwards
- a button (btnRemove) to remove the control

When I press button "btnAddControl", add a new UControl to the placeholder "PlaceHolderUC";

Everything works fine; even removing the control, when I press the "btnRemove" button, works.

[Page after adding 4 UControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mT4Q.png)

The problem occurs when I want to move the controls by pressing the "btnMoveDown" and "btnMoveUp" buttons.
The logical move works, but the panel is not updated.

[I pressed the "btnMoveDown" button on Control # 2; it updated the sort textbox (txtOrder) field but did not physically move the controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW5EZ.png)

To update the panel I have to press the "btnRefreshPage" button.

I tried adding the `UPanel.Update();` command after the button is pressed, but that doesn't work either.

The list "UControlList" is used to keep data persistence.

I also tried moving component loading from Page_Load to other page events, but it still doesn't work

This is my code.

**default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestUpdatePanel._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Test Update Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

      <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddControl" runat="server" Text="Add control" OnClick="btnAddControl_Click" />
      </p>

      <asp:ScriptManager ID="SManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderUC" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddControl" EventName="Click" />
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefreshPage" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>

      <asp:Button ID="btnRefreshPage" runat="server" Text="Refresh Page" OnClick="btnRefreshPage_Click" />

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestUpdatePanel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class UControlClass
    {
        public UControlClass()
        {
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public String Label { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public List<UControlClass> UControlList
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["UControlList"] == null)
                    ViewState["UControlList"] = new List<UControlClass>();
                return (List<UControlClass>)ViewState["UControlList"];
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["UControlList"] = value;
            }
        }

        private void ReloadControls()
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var tmp in UControlList.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
            {
                i++;

                var c = (UControl)LoadControl("UControl.ascx");
                c.ID = "C_" + tmp.ID.ToString();
                c.Label = tmp.Label;
                c.IsFirst = (i == 1);
                c.IsLast = (i == UControlList.Count);
                c.BtnRemoveClickEvent += C_BtnRemoveClickEvent;
                c.BtnMoveUpClickEvent += C_BtnMoveUpClickEvent;
                c.BtnMoveDownClickEvent += C_BtnMoveDownClickEvent;

                PlaceHolderUC.Controls.Add(c);
            }
        }
        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReloadControls();
        }

        private void RefreshSorting()
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var tmp in UControlList.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
            {
                i++;

                var c = (UControl)PlaceHolderUC.FindControl("C_" + tmp.ID.ToString());
                if (c == null)
                    return;

                c.IsFirst = (i == 1);
                c.IsLast = (i == UControlList.Count);
            }
        }

        protected void btnAddControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UControlClass UClass = new UControlClass();
            UClass.ID = UControlList.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(x => x == null ? 0 : x.ID) + 1;
            UClass.Order = UControlList.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(x => x == null ? 0 : x.Order) + 1;
            UClass.Label = "Control # " + UClass.ID.ToString();

            var c = (UControl)LoadControl("UControl.ascx");
            c.ID = "C_" + UClass.ID.ToString();
            c.Order = UClass.Order;
            c.Label = UClass.Label;
            c.BtnRemoveClickEvent += C_BtnRemoveClickEvent;
            c.BtnMoveUpClickEvent += C_BtnMoveUpClickEvent;
            c.BtnMoveDownClickEvent += C_BtnMoveDownClickEvent;
            c.IsFirst = (UControlList.Count == 0);
            c.IsLast = true;

            UControlList.Add(UClass);

            PlaceHolderUC.Controls.Add(c);

            RefreshSorting();
        }

        private void C_BtnMoveDownClickEvent(object sender, UControlEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var CurrentControl = (UControl)PlaceHolderUC.FindControl("C_" + e.ID.ToString());

                var CurrentList = UControlList.Find(x => x.ID == e.ID);

                if (CurrentControl == null || CurrentList == null || CurrentControl.Order != CurrentList.Order)
                    return;

                var NextList = UControlList.OrderBy(x => x.Order).Reverse().TakeWhile(x => x.Order > CurrentControl.Order).LastOrDefault();

                if (NextList == null)
                    return;

                var NextControl = (UControl)PlaceHolderUC.FindControl("C_" + NextList.ID.ToString());

                if (NextControl == null || NextControl.Order != NextList.Order)
                    return;

                Int32 tmp = CurrentControl.Order;

                CurrentControl.Order = NextControl.Order;
                CurrentList.Order = NextControl.Order;
                NextControl.Order = tmp;
                NextList.Order = tmp;

                RefreshSorting();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void C_BtnMoveUpClickEvent(object sender, UControlEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var CurrentControl = (UControl)PlaceHolderUC.FindControl("C_" + e.ID.ToString());

                var CurrentList = UControlList.Find(x => x.ID == e.ID);

                if (CurrentControl == null || CurrentList == null || CurrentControl.Order != CurrentList.Order)
                    return;

                var PreviousList = UControlList.OrderBy(x => x.Order).TakeWhile(x => x.Order < CurrentControl.Order).LastOrDefault();

                if (PreviousList == null)
                    return;

                var PreviousControl = (UControl)PlaceHolderUC.FindControl("C_" + PreviousList.ID.ToString());

                if (PreviousControl == null || PreviousControl.Order != PreviousList.Order)
                    return;

                Int32 tmp = CurrentControl.Order;

                CurrentControl.Order = PreviousControl.Order;
                CurrentList.Order = PreviousControl.Order;
                PreviousControl.Order = tmp;
                PreviousList.Order = tmp;

                RefreshSorting();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void C_BtnRemoveClickEvent(object sender, UControlEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var c = (UControl)PlaceHolderUC.FindControl("C_" + e.ID.ToString());

                if (c == null)
                    return;

                UControlList.RemoveAll(x => x.ID == e.ID);

                PlaceHolderUC.Controls.Remove(c);

                c.Dispose();

                RefreshSorting();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected void btnRefreshPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do nothing...
        }
    }
}
```

**UControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestUpdatePanel.UControl" %>

<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrder" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Button ID="btnMoveDown" runat="server" Text="Down" OnClick="btnMoveDown_Click" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Button ID="btnMoveUp" runat="server" Text="Up" OnClick="btnMoveUp_Click" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<hr />
```

**UControl.ascx.cs**

```
using System;

namespace TestUpdatePanel
{
    public class UControlEventArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
        public Int32 ID { get; }
        public UControlEventArgs(Int32 id)
        {
            ID = id;
        }
    }
    public partial class UControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public String Label
        {
            get { return lblTest.Text; }
            set { lblTest.Text = value; }
        }

        public Int32 Order
        {
            get { return Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text); }
            set { txtOrder.Text = value.ToString(); }
        }

        private Boolean _IsFirst;
        public Boolean IsFirst
        {
            get { return _IsFirst; }
            set
            {
                _IsFirst = value;
                btnMoveUp.Enabled = !_IsFirst;
            }
        }

        private Boolean _IsLast;
        public Boolean IsLast
        {
            get { return _IsLast; }
            set
            {
                _IsLast = value;
                btnMoveDown.Enabled = !_IsLast;
            }
        }

        public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, UControlEventArgs e);

        public event MyEventHandler BtnRemoveClickEvent;
        public event MyEventHandler BtnMoveUpClickEvent;
        public event MyEventHandler BtnMoveDownClickEvent;

        private void OnBtnRemoveClickEvent(int ID)
        {
            BtnRemoveClickEvent?.Invoke(this, new UControlEventArgs(ID));
        }

        protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnBtnRemoveClickEvent(Convert.ToInt32(ID.Replace("C_", "")));
        }

        private void OnBtnMoveUpClickEvent(int ID)
        {
            BtnMoveUpClickEvent?.Invoke(this, new UControlEventArgs(ID));
        }

        protected void btnMoveUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnBtnMoveUpClickEvent(Convert.ToInt32(ID.Replace("C_", "")));
        }

        private void OnBtnMoveDownClickEvent(int ID)
        {
            BtnMoveDownClickEvent?.Invoke(this, new UControlEventArgs(ID));
        }

        protected void btnMoveDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnBtnMoveDownClickEvent(Convert.ToInt32(ID.Replace("C_", "")));
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Any suggestions, even for non-issue topics, are welcome.

Thanks to whoever answers me.

It would be very important for me to solve the problem because it is a work project.

Comment: have you tried to see if doing a postback trigger vs a asyncpostback trigge makes a differnce?

Comment: What do the question marks do? `BtnMoveUpClickEvent?.Invoke` (same with down).

Comment: ? is the null conditional operator. Introduced in the 6th version of C#, helps you to write less code for handling null checks; is also thread-safe! 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#thread-safe-delegate-invocation

Comment: Maybe I solve my problem calling
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "__doPostBack('" + UPanel.ClientID + "', '');", true);